# Small generic path search framework in Java

Tags: java, search, graph, pathfinding, framework

I have this small generic path search library. It's not perfect at all, so I need some comments as to have a chance to improve it.

**com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model**:

*AbstractHeuristicFunction.java*:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model;

public interface AbstractHeuristicFunction<T extends AbstractNode<T>> {

    public void setTarget(final T target);

    public void setLayout(final PlaneLayout layout);

    public double h(final T node);
}
```

*AbstractNode.java*:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model;

public abstract class AbstractNode<T extends AbstractNode<T>> 
implements Iterable<T> {

    protected final String id;

    protected AbstractNode(final String id) {
        if (id == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The ID string is null.");
        }

        this.id = id;
    }

    public abstract boolean connectTo(final T node);

    public abstract boolean disconnectFrom(final T node);

    public abstract boolean isConnectedTo(final T node);

    public abstract Iterable<T> parents();

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof AbstractNode)) {
            return false;
        }

        return (((AbstractNode<T>) o).id.equals(this.id));
    }
}
```

*AbstractWeightFunction.java*:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public abstract class AbstractWeightFunction<T extends AbstractNode<T>> {

    protected final Map<T, Map<T, Double>> map;

    protected AbstractWeightFunction() {
        this.map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public abstract Double put(final T node1, 
                               final T node2, 
                               final double weight);

    public abstract double get(final T node1, final T node2);
}
```

*AbstractPathFinder.java*:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public abstract class AbstractPathFinder<T extends AbstractNode<T>> {

    public abstract List<T> search(final T source, final T target);

    protected List<T> constructPath(final T middleNode, 
                                    final Map<T, T> parentMapA,
                                    final Map<T, T> parentMapB) {
        final List<T> path = new ArrayList<>();
        T current = middleNode;

        while (current != null) {
            path.add(current);
            current = parentMapA.get(current);
        }

        Collections.<T>reverse(path);

        if (parentMapB != null) {
            current = parentMapB.get(middleNode);

            while (current != null) {
                path.add(current);
                current = parentMapB.get(current);
            }
        }

        return path;
    }

    protected List<T> constructPath(final T target, final Map<T, T> parentMap) {
        return constructPath(target, parentMap, null);
    }
}
```

*PlaneLayout.java*:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PlaneLayout<T extends AbstractNode<T>> {

    private final Map<T, Point2D.Double> map;

    public PlaneLayout() {
        this.map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Point2D.Double put(final T node, final Point2D.Double location) {
        return map.put(node, location);
    }

    public Point2D.Double get(final T node) {
        return map.get(node);
    }
}
```

**com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.support**:

*AStarPathFinder.java*:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.support;

import static com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.Utils.checkNotNull;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.AbstractHeuristicFunction;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.AbstractNode;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.AbstractWeightFunction;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.AbstractPathFinder;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Set;

public class AStarPathFinder<T extends AbstractNode<T>>
extends AbstractPathFinder<T> {

    private AbstractHeuristicFunction<T> heuristicFunction;
    private AbstractWeightFunction<T> weightFunction;

    private final Map<T, T> PARENTS;
    private final Map<T, Double> DISTANCE;
    private final Set<T> CLOSED;
    private PriorityQueue<T> OPEN;

    public AStarPathFinder() {
        this.PARENTS = new HashMap<>();
        this.DISTANCE = new HashMap<>();
        this.CLOSED = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> search(T source, T target) {
        checkNotNull(heuristicFunction, "Heuristic function is null.");
        checkNotNull(weightFunction, "Weight function is null.");

        clearState();

        heuristicFunction.setTarget(target);

        OPEN.add(source);
        PARENTS.put(source, null);
        DISTANCE.put(source, 0.0);

        while (OPEN.size() > 0) {
            final T current = OPEN.poll();

            if (current.equals(target)) {
                return constructPath(target, PARENTS);
            }

            CLOSED.add(current);

            for (final T child : current) {
                if (CLOSED.contains(child)) {
                    continue;
                }

                final double w = g(current) + w(current, child);

                if (!PARENTS.containsKey(child)) {
                    PARENTS.put(child, current);
                    DISTANCE.put(child, w);
                    // DISTANCE updated, implicitly used by OPEN.add.
                    OPEN.add(child);
                } else if (w < g(child)) {
                    PARENTS.put(child, current);
                    DISTANCE.put(child, w);
                    // Reinsert as to decrease the priority.
                    OPEN.remove(child);
                    OPEN.add(child);
                }
            }
        }

        // Empty list denotes that target is not reachable from source.
        return Collections.<T>emptyList();
    }

    public AStarPathFinder<T>  
        setWeightFunction(final AbstractWeightFunction<T> function) {
        this.weightFunction = function;
        return this;
    }

    public AStarPathFinder<T>
        setHeuristicFunction(final AbstractHeuristicFunction<T> function) {
        this.heuristicFunction = function;
        this.OPEN = new PriorityQueue<>(
                new FValueComparator(DISTANCE, function));
        return this;
    }

    private double h(final T node) {
        return heuristicFunction.h(node);
    }

    private double w(final T tail, final T head) {
        return weightFunction.get(tail, head);
    }

    private double g(final T node) {
        return DISTANCE.get(node);
    }

    private void clearState() {
        PARENTS.clear();
        DISTANCE.clear();
        CLOSED.clear();
        OPEN.clear();
    }

    private class FValueComparator implements Comparator<T> {

        private final Map<T, Double> DISTANCE;
        private final AbstractHeuristicFunction<T> function;

        FValueComparator(final Map<T, Double> DISTANCE,
                         final AbstractHeuristicFunction<T> function) {
            this.DISTANCE = DISTANCE;
            this.function = function;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(final T o1, final T o2) {
            final double f1 = DISTANCE.get(o1) + function.h(o1);
            final double f2 = DISTANCE.get(o2) + function.h(o2);
            return Double.compare(f1, f2);
        }
    }
}
```

*DijkstraHeuristicFunction.java*:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.support;

import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.AbstractHeuristicFunction;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.AbstractNode;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.PlaneLayout;

public class DijkstraHeuristicFunction<T extends AbstractNode<T>> 
implements AbstractHeuristicFunction<T> {

    @Override
    public double h(T node) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTarget(T target) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setLayout(PlaneLayout layout) {

    }
}
```

*DirectedGraphNode.java*:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.support;

import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.AbstractNode;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class DirectedGraphNode extends AbstractNode<DirectedGraphNode> {

    private final Set<DirectedGraphNode> in;
    private final Set<DirectedGraphNode> out;

    public DirectedGraphNode(final String id) {
        super(id);
        // LinkedHashSet iterates way faster than HashSet.
        this.in  = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        this.out = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean connectTo(DirectedGraphNode node) {
        if (out.contains(node)) {
            return false;
        }

        out.add(node);
        node.in.add(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean disconnectFrom(DirectedGraphNode node) {
        if (!out.contains(node)) {
            return false;
        }

        out.remove(node);
        node.in.remove(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConnectedTo(DirectedGraphNode node) {
        return out.contains(node);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<DirectedGraphNode> parents() {
        return new Iterable<DirectedGraphNode>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<DirectedGraphNode> iterator() {
                return new IteratorProxy<>(in.iterator());
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<DirectedGraphNode> iterator() {
        return new IteratorProxy<>(out.iterator());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[DirectedGraphNode " + id + "]";
    }
}
```

*DirectedGraphWeightFunction.java*:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.support;

import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.AbstractWeightFunction;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DirectedGraphWeightFunction 
extends AbstractWeightFunction<DirectedGraphNode> {

    public DirectedGraphWeightFunction() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Double put(final DirectedGraphNode node1, 
                      final DirectedGraphNode node2, 
                      final double weight) {
        if (!map.containsKey(node1)) {
            map.put(node1, new HashMap<>());
        }

        final Double old = map.get(node1).get(node2);
        map.get(node1).put(node2, weight);
        return old;
    }

    @Override
    public double get(final DirectedGraphNode node1, 
                      final DirectedGraphNode node2) {
        return map.get(node1).get(node2);
    }
}
```

*IteratorProxy.java*:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.support;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class IteratorProxy<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private final Iterator<T> iterator;

    protected IteratorProxy(final Iterator<T> iterator) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iterator.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        return iterator.next();
    }
}
```

*PlaneHeuristicFunction.java*:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.support;

import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.AbstractHeuristicFunction;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.AbstractNode;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.PlaneLayout;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class PlaneHeuristicFunction<T extends AbstractNode<T>> 
implements AbstractHeuristicFunction<T> {

    private T target;
    private PlaneLayout<T> layout;
    private Point2D.Double targetLocation;

    public PlaneHeuristicFunction(final PlaneLayout<T> layout,
                                  final T target) {
        this.layout = layout;
        this.targetLocation = layout.get(target);
    }

    @Override
    public void setLayout(PlaneLayout layout) {
        this.layout = layout;
        this.targetLocation = layout.get(target);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTarget(T target) {
        this.target = target;
        this.targetLocation = layout.get(target);
    }

    @Override
    public double h(final T node) {
        return targetLocation.distance(layout.get(node));
    }
}
```

**com.stackexchange.codereview.graph**:

*Utils.java*:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.graph;

import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.PlaneLayout;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.support.DirectedGraphNode;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.support.DirectedGraphWeightFunction;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Utils {

    public static class Triple<F, S, T> {
        private final F first;
        private final S second;
        private final T third;

        public Triple(final F first, final S second, final T third) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
            this.third = third;
        }

        public F first() {
            return first;
        }

        public S second() {
            return second;
        }

        public T third() {
            return third;
        }
    }

    public static Triple<List<DirectedGraphNode>,
                         DirectedGraphWeightFunction,
                         PlaneLayout>
        createRandomDigraph(final int nodeAmount,
                            float edgeLoadFactor,
                            final double width,
                            final double height,
                            final double maxDistance,
                            double weightFactor,
                            final Random rnd) {
        final List<DirectedGraphNode> graph = new ArrayList<>(nodeAmount);
        final PlaneLayout layout = new PlaneLayout();
        final DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction =
                new DirectedGraphWeightFunction();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeAmount; ++i) {
            final DirectedGraphNode node = new DirectedGraphNode("" + i);
            layout.put(node, new Point2D.Double(width * rnd.nextDouble(),
                                                height * rnd.nextDouble()));
            graph.add(node);
        }

        weightFactor = Math.max(weightFactor, 1.05);
        edgeLoadFactor = Math.min(edgeLoadFactor, 0.8f);
        int edges = (int)(edgeLoadFactor * nodeAmount * nodeAmount);

        while (edges > 0) {
            final DirectedGraphNode tail = choose(graph, rnd);
            final DirectedGraphNode head = choose(graph, rnd);

            final Point2D.Double tailPoint = layout.get(tail);
            final Point2D.Double headPoint = layout.get(head);

            final double distance = tailPoint.distance(headPoint);

            if (distance <= maxDistance) {
                tail.connectTo(head);
                weightFunction.put(tail, head, weightFactor * distance);
                --edges;
            }
        }

        return new Triple<>(graph, weightFunction, layout);
    }

    public static <E> E choose(final List<E> list, final Random rnd) {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return list.get(rnd.nextInt(list.size()));
    }

    public static void checkNotNull(final Object reference, 
                                    final String message) {
        if (reference == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException(message);
        }
    }

    public static <E> boolean listsAreSame(final List<E> list1, 
                                           final List<E> list2) {
        if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); ++i) {
            if (!list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

*Demo.java*:

```
package com.stackexchange.codereview.graph;

import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.Utils.Triple;
import static com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.Utils.choose;
import static com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.Utils.listsAreSame;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.PlaneLayout;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.support.AStarPathFinder;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.support.DijkstraHeuristicFunction;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.support.DirectedGraphNode;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.support.DirectedGraphWeightFunction;
import com.stackexchange.codereview.graph.model.support.PlaneHeuristicFunction;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Demo {

    public static final int GRAPH_SIZE = 100000;
    public static final float EDGE_LOAD_FACTOR = 4.0f / GRAPH_SIZE;
    public static final double WIDTH = 2000.0;
    public static final double HEIGHT = 1000.0;
    public static final double MAX_DISTANCE = 100.0;
    public static final double WEIGHT_FACTOR = 1.1;

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Seed: " + seed);

        final Random rnd = new Random(seed);

        Triple<List<DirectedGraphNode>,
               DirectedGraphWeightFunction, 
               PlaneLayout> data = 
                Utils.createRandomDigraph(GRAPH_SIZE,
                                          EDGE_LOAD_FACTOR, 
                                          WIDTH,
                                          HEIGHT, 
                                          MAX_DISTANCE,
                                          WEIGHT_FACTOR,
                                          rnd);

        final DirectedGraphNode source = choose(data.first(), rnd);
        final DirectedGraphNode target = choose(data.first(), rnd);

        System.out.println("Source: " + source);
        System.out.println("Target: " + target);

        final AStarPathFinder<DirectedGraphNode> finder =
                new AStarPathFinder<>()
                .setHeuristicFunction(
                        new PlaneHeuristicFunction<>(data.third(), target))
                .setWeightFunction(data.second());


        long ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

        final List<DirectedGraphNode> path1 = finder.search(source, target);

        long tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("A* in " + (tb - ta) + " ms.");

        for (final DirectedGraphNode node : path1) {
            System.out.println(node);
        }

        System.out.println();

        finder.setHeuristicFunction(new DijkstraHeuristicFunction<>());

        ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

        final List<DirectedGraphNode> path2 = finder.search(source, target);

        tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Dijkstra's algorithm in " + (tb - ta) + " ms.");

        for (final DirectedGraphNode node : path2) {
            System.out.println(node);
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Paths are same: " + listsAreSame(path1, path2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework, personal project, or production code?

Comment: Personal project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Utils

Statically importing these methods is questionable - it makes it harder to read code without consulting the list of imports.

Triple

Don't do this. Use a real class that contains the data you need. Maybe `DirectedGraph` would be a good name.

choose()

Should be named better - `selectRandomNode()`, perhaps.

#### AbstractHeuristicFunction

The name 'Abstract' should be reserved for use only by classes modified with the `abstract` keyword. By convention, java interfaces have no indicator that they are interfaces.

#### AbstractNode

Methods not intended to be extended by children should be explicitly declared `final` to prevent such extension. The `id` instance variable should be private, unless you really intend for subtypes to be able to manually change it after the instance has been constructed.

#### AStarPathFinder

Don't allow objects to be built in an invalid state. If this class *needs* heuristic and weight functions, require them in the constructor/static factory method/builder.

#### Documentation

You don't have any, which is less than optimal. It's great when you can hover over a method in your IDE and see exactly how it's supposed to work. At the very least, all public methods should be documented, so clients using your library can easily understand how your code works.

#### General Design

I'm an API designer, so I tend to look at things from that perspective.

I think that an interface called `Graph` should be the main entry point into your system. `DirectedGraph` should be an implementation of that interface. You can take out a lot of the generics noise if you do that. Likewise, add a `GraphNode` interface that `DirectedGraphNode` implements. Many existing methods would belong to `Graph`, such as `finder.search()`. You could either pass in the relevant arguments or use a fluent API. Weights should be a property of the `Graph`, since different implementations behave differently. You should be able to share a lot of implementation behind the scenes when you add an undirected graph, since that's just a special case of a directed graph (both directions always have the same weight). You should even be able to modify the `createRandomGraph()` method to take an enum argument specifying the graph type (GraphType.DIRECTED or GraphType.UNDIRECTED).

Those changes would make your Demo class look something like:

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
    final long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Seed: " + seed);

    final Random rnd = new Random(seed);

    final Graph diGraph =
            Utils.createRandomDigraph(GRAPH_SIZE,
                                      EDGE_LOAD_FACTOR,
                                      WIDTH,
                                      HEIGHT,
                                      MAX_DISTANCE,
                                      WEIGHT_FACTOR,
                                      rnd);

    final GraphNode source = diGraph.selectRandomNode();
    final GraphNode target = diGraph.selectRandomNode();

    System.out.println("Source: " + source);
    System.out.println("Target: " + target);

    final Heuristic aStarHeuristic = new AStarHeuristic();

    long ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

    final List<GraphNode> path1 =
            diGraph.findPath(source, target, aStarHeuristic);
    /* OR
     * diGraph.findPathFrom(source).to(target).usingHeuristic(aStar);
     */


    long tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("A* in " + (tb - ta) + " ms.");

    for (final GraphNode node : path1) {
        System.out.println(node);
    }

    // ... etc
```

You should also really consider using the Builder pattern to create graph instances. You've pushed past the suggested number of input parameters to a method, which makes it harder to read/understand code written against the API, and also makes it harder to remember parameter order. In order to do that, you'd need reasonable defaults for many of the arguments, because you need to assume that clients may not set anything they don't have to. You could solve that problem with a fluent API chain instead of a builder, but that's more work for you as a developer. In a real API I'd say go for it, but if this is just a personal project it probably isn't worth it unless you want to play with fluent APIs.

There are more specific issues that could be raised, but I think that's enough for a start. Many of them would change if you switch your design around.